# Export pytest results even when AssertionError

Tags: python, pytest, logfile, tox

I have a tox file which run pytest on my project and export test results when all of them passed but when one of them failed, and I get an AssertionError, I can not save my logs in my results file. Have you any idea or solution to save logs even when tests failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `try` and `except` statements to handle exceptions

Example:

```
try:
     #put your pytest stuff here
except AssertionError:
    pass
```

If all goes well your log should be saved in no time!